# UIAlertController automatically dismisses in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, ios10, appdelegate, uialertcontroller

I have a `UIAlertController` in my `AppDelegate` and present it with my `rootViewController` when I receive a notification. But when the alert view pops up, it quickly dismisses itself instead of waiting for a tap event on the "Ok" button... Here's my code in `AppDelegate.m`. Any idea? Thanks!

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    [self showNotification:"Success message here"];
}

- (void)showNotification:(NSString *)text {
    UIAlertController* avc = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success" message:text
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
    [avc addAction:ok];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:avc animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT**: I have another view controller; call it X. X's `viewDidLoad` function has a timer counting down before X dismisses itself and presents another view controller. I noticed an interesting timing issue here: when the notification comes slowly enough so that the `UIAlertController` appears after X's timer is up and another view controller has been presented, the alertController doesn't dismiss itself. If the opposite happens - the notification comes quickly enough making the `UIAlertController` appears before X dismisses itself, then the whole AlertController will be flushed when the timer is up (which makes sense, I guess...). How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: If the dismissal is caused by other code, you need to _show that code_. We need enough code that we can reproduce the problem (that means make the very same thing happen on our own computer), and you have not provided it. With the code _you_ have shown, the alert is _never_ dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use perform selector method, like this:

```
- (void)showNotification:(NSString *)text {
  UIAlertController* avc = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success" message:text
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
  UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
 [avc addAction:ok];

  [self performSelector:@selector(dissmissAlert:) withObject:avc afterDelay:3.0];

  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:avc animated:true completion:nil];
}
-(void)dissmissAlert:(UIAlertController *) alert{
  [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: It's cleaner, safer, and more versatile to use `dispatch_after` instead of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.